# Azure Pipelines - Download files with azcopy

Tags: azure-pipelines

I can see there is a task to upload local files to Azure storage or VM. But how can we download from blob or file share into the pipeline agent? Currently I am using azcopy with a SAS URI. Is there a task in Pipelines that will do this using a service connection instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So since I am downloading files from Azure Storage Share (Not blob or container) azcopy works out to be a hell of a lot faster. Using `az storage file download-batch` was way too slow. Instead we can just use bash to call azcopy.

**Install azcopy in pipeline agent**

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install azcopy
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      mkdir $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy
      wget -O $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy_v10.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux
      tar -xf $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy_v10.tar.gz -C $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy --strip-components=1
```

**Download with azcopy using az-cli task**

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Download using azcopy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Service-Connection'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      end=`date -u -d "180 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00Z'`
      sas=$(az storage share generate-sas -n share-name --account-name account-name --https-only --permissions lr --expiry $end -o tsv)
      $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy copy "https://account-name.file.core.windows.net/share-name/folder/?$sas" "/Download-Path" --recursive --check-md5=FailIfDifferent
```

Comment: I have opened an issue concerning the performance issue of `az storage file download-batch` at https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14374.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we don't have such task can direct satisfied your requirement. But you can utilize the Azure CLi task to execute the command.

As an example, I can execute [az storage blob download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) command in Azure cli to download files from Azure Blob Storage:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: {service connection}
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     mkdir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/BlobFile
     az storage blob download --container-name $(containername) --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/BlobFile --name "{file name}" --account-key $(accountkey) --account-name $(accountname)
```

The logic of my suggestion is using `mkdir` to create a folder in current directory, then download file from blob and save it into this folder. You can follow this to execute your `azcopy` command.

We have integrated the service connection into this task, so you can configure the service connection to connect to your Azure blob. Then select it in this Azure cli task.

Comment: The storage we have is in an Azure File Share. So i'm currently using "az storage file download-batch", which is extremely slow.

I could use azcopy in a shell task, however I haven't seen a way to generate SAS tokens for Azure File Shares that include list permissions.

Is there a way we can automate the generation of a SAS token to include list permissions when using "az storage file generate-sas"?

Comment: @philthy, What does "automate the generation of a SAS token" mean?

Comment: See below, there is a way we can generate the SAS token with Azure CLI instead of via the portal. With that I can automate a pipeline to download via azcopy.

Answer (score 0):

For me [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688987/3447047) by @philthy didn't work because I ran into [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/122) issue in the `Azure/azure-storage-azcopy` GitHub repo.

The following *did* work for me.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install azcopy
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      mkdir $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy && cd "$_"
      wget -O azcopy_v10.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux
      tar -xf azcopy_v10.tar.gz --strip-components=1
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Download using azcopy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: my-vmssagents-service-connection
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      export STORE_NAME="data"
      export CONTAINER_NAME="data"
      export FOLDER="my_folder"

      NOW=`date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00Z"` \
      EXPIRY=`date -d "$NOW + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00Z"` \
      && export SAS_TOKEN=$( az storage container generate-sas \
          --account-name $STORE_NAME \
          --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
          --start $NOW \
          --expiry $EXPIRY \
          --permissions acdlrw \
          --output tsv )

      $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy copy \
          "https://${STORE_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${CONTAINER_NAME}/${FOLDER}/?${SAS_TOKEN}" \
          "." --recursive --include-pattern "*c_*b.nc;left.nc;right.nc" # <-- my specific pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've just run an az storage copy that under the hood uses azcopy:

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Migrate to GZRS"
        inputs:
          failOnStandardError: false
          azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
              az storage copy -s https://$(storageAccountTerraform).blob.core.windows.net/ -d https://$(storageAccountTerraformGZRS).blob.core.windows.net/ --recursive
```

Ans azcopy uses the credentials specified in the Service Connection, passed via the azureSubscription input, therefore no need to pass anything else:

```
WARNING: Azcopy command: ['/home/AzDevOps/bin/azcopy', 'copy', 
'https://YOUR_SOURCE_SA.blob.core.windows.net/?se=2023-11-08T13%3A15%3A53Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sig=', 'https://YOUR_DESTINATION_SA.blob.core.windows.net/?se=2023-11-08T13%3A15%3A53Z&sp=wac&sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=co&sig=', '--recursive']
```