# How to copy data from private S3 bucket to Azure Blob storage via Azure yaml pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have one S3 bucket storing CSV files in it. New CSV files get added to this bucket at the beginning of each month. I want these new files to be uploaded automatically to the Azure blob storage at the beginning of each month.

The way I was thinking to do this is to create a script(bash/PowerShell) that pulls data from the AWS S3 bucket to Azure blob storage via [AZ Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2ffiles%2ftoc.json#download-azcopy) command. and then plug this script into an Azure YAML pipeline which runs every start of the month to execute this script. but I can't find a way to integrate this script in an Azure YAML pipeline. Is this command feasible with the YAML pipeline? or is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can copy data from S3 bucket to Azure Blob Storage using azcopy.

```
azcopy copy "<s3-bucket-uri>" "https://StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/?sas-token" --recursive
```

We can integrate the azcopy with YAML pipeline.

**Firstly, install azcopy in pipeline agent** as below :

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install azcopy
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      mkdir $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy
      wget -O $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy_v10.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux
      tar -xf $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy_v10.tar.gz -C $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy --strip-components=1
```

**Create cli-task with azcopy in pipeline** to copy data from S3 bucket to Azure Blob Storage using azcopy

Reference code :

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Download using azcopy
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Service-Connection'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      end=`date -u -d "180 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:00Z'`
      $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/azcopy/azcopy copy "<s3-bucket-uri>" "https://StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/?sas-token" --recursive --check-md5=FailIfDifferent
```

Reference SO thread : [Azure Pipelines - Download files with azcopy - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668960/azure-pipelines-download-files-with-azcopy)

Comment: thx for responding. I am yet not clear on how do you authenticate AWS IAM credentials here to copy data from a private S3 bucket? Moreover, how to authenticate Azure storage in this AzureCLI@2 task, if I don't have SAS token?

Comment: thx for responding. I am yet not clear on how do you authenticate AWS IAM credentials here to copy data from a private S3 bucket? Moreover, how to authenticate Azure storage in this AzureCLI@2 task, if I don't have SAS token? @RamaraoAdapa-MT

Comment: do you have aws account access key id and the access key. Also do you have storage account key ?